# Should you use the same Google Analytics property for your website and YouTube channel?

Tags: google-analytics, youtube

I've setup a YouTube channel to host some of my site's videos on and to share on social media. I'd like to add Google Analytics to it now but I'm not sure if I should use my website's property or setup a new property for the YouTube channel.

What are the pros/cons of using the same property, or is it best to always setup a new property just for the YouTube channel?

Answer (score 3):

This decision has nothing to do whether it is a YouTube channel, and nobody can answer this without knowing the contents of those two assets.

You can think of a Google Analytics property to be just that: a *property*, a discrete thing you own.

Let’s imagine somebody offered you money for either your website or your YouTube channel. Would it really only make sense to sell the two things as a package? If so, put them in the same Analytics property.

This is why options like “Industry Category” are [tracked at the property level](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3467852?hl=en) in analytics: you might have a side business selling widgets, and other one about collecting sprockets. These would be separate properties, and each could contain whatever sites you’d created for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync your google analytics and youtube easily.  Copy your google **anlytics ua-code** under channel>advanced. From their you will be able to copy and paste your analytics account number into youtube and track your youtube stats through analytics.  You may want to setup a filter view to filter out the youtube traffic, but you can't just copy and paste the Analytics code, you need to use the tools in your channel.

https://www.youtube.com/advanced_settings all the way at the bottom you type in your analytics ua code.

You can segment the data in Analytics so no need to create two completely different properties.